# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at ListView android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am facing some strange issue in the `ListView` when I set a footer view. I'm adding the footer link to load more on reaching the end element in `ListView`, and removing it when it's loaded. **And the `ListView` is backed with `CursorAdapter`**.

It was working well without any issue till Kitkat, but with android L update when I change fragment while loading more elements, it crashes with following trace:

```
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3307)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4083)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14048)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14048)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1057)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14048)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3210)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
11-15 17:20:19.532: E/AndroidRuntime(11784):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
```

When I remove the footer it is working fine. I'm loading more with `AsyncTask` and inserting the values in the table, and notify changes using `notifyChange`.

I don't know what am I doing wrong. It would be nice if someone tell me about this issue.

Comment: show your code where the error is

Comment: do you use a cursor loader?

Comment: Yes, I am using CursorLoader. The error is not in my code.. But I didn't know exactly which is causing me the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same problem / same stacktrace. In my case I'm using support v4 library for Fragments and using setCustomAnimations during adding Fragment. The problem stop happening when I didn't set popExit animation. Maybe this is also your case.
I didn't find any other workaround and I think it's just bug in support library. Useful topics 
[Remove with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655207/indexoutofboundsexception-when-removing-a-listview-item-with-delay) or [Animation between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments).

Comment: Same problem, removing setTransaction({ANY}) solved the problem

Comment: Same problem, but I did not have header/footer. Was some kind of race condition between list items being updated that caused this crash. I removed animation and there is no crash. But I need animation so I added (        if (position >= listItems.size()) ) return false; to isEnabled() instead.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by calling:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

and then:

```
list.removeFooterView(footerVIew)
```